# Changing baseURL in symfony of all controllers

Tags: apache, symfony, routes

So I'm hosting my application in a subdirectory on apache server under `/~test/`
I've tried adding prefix in routes with nothing happening

I want all routes of all my controllers to start with `/~test/` without me adding that manually to each route. Right now when a route goes to / it goes outside of my `/~test/` directory

for example:

```
  /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
    }
```

This route I'd want to go to `/~test/login`

My .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Add SetEnv BASE "/test" to .htaccess

Comment: @mblaettermann Tried, that put it on the top of the htaccess with no result, it could be because of the apache setup I don't know if it allows overrides I have no access to the root config

Comment: your Symfony version? Also copy-paste your main URL

Comment: @Trix symfony 4.1 my url is on intranet basically uni.co.uk/~myusername/

Comment: and you want your symfony application homepage at `http://uni.co.uk/~myusername/test/` ? or what ever else?

Comment: @Trix no sorry the test was an example by test i actually meant ~username, so the homepage would be http://uni.co.uk/~myusername/index.php and login http://uni.co.uk/~myusername/login etc.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful and helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Look at that https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-prefix-imported-route-names

You can write something like this in your routes.yaml file:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /cool-prefix
```

Answer (score 1):

1. > my application in a subdirectory on apache server under /~test/
2. > the test was an example by test i actually meant ~username
3. > the homepage would be uni.co.uk/~myusername/index.php

Put this on your application root directory's `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```